# "Blank screen" after inactivity not really blank - mouse cursor stays

Tags: 20.04, power-management

There is something wrong with the Power saving's "Blank screen". I've recently upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04. Blank screen is set to activate after 4 mins of inactivity. The problem is that the screen is going blank, but the mouse cursor is still shown and prevents monitor from suspending.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this happens quite often with AMD GPUs + some HDMI connected monitors and it is caused by hotplug events.

TL;TR:
Boot your linux with amdgpu.dc=0 in the grub's command line.

More info and bug tracking here:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/662

Answer (score 1):

The mouse showing is a symptom, not a cause of the screen not going into power saving mode.   I believe (but can't prove) there are bugs in the high level screen saver settings that prevent the low level X11 screen saver from properly trigger power saving.

Also, some applications (video viewers, games, some full screen apps) disable screen blanking and power saving and the screen blanker does not automatically re-enable it reliably.

At a low level, you can check this with the xset command: `xset -q` and look for the DPMS settings:

```
  DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 300    Suspend: 400    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

- If DPMS is disabled, you can enable it with `xset +dpms`
- If you want to change the timings (in seconds), use for example `xset dpms 300 400 600` ; the times correspond to increasingly deeper levels of power saving, which was relevant for CRTs but is probably moot for LCDs and other modern screens that power back on instantly.
- If you just want to force the screen off immediately, `xset dpms force off`

Note, however, that the the last item will only work briefly if you try to activate it with a mouse.  A few second delay before it will give you time to let go of the mouse before it runs.

In the past, you could set these things and forget them and it would work.  However, modern graphical shells mess with them, and don't provide a direct way to set them, and a few applications change them as well, so setting them directly is not reliable unless you reset them to what you want periodically.  Also, some screen blankers don't use the timeout settings in DPMS and zero those, and then run dpms force off themselves when they feel like it.

But if your screen is not powering down, you can at least use these commands to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your info. DPMS is Enabled, "xset dpms force off" switches off the screen for a few seconds (monitor shows message "No signal") but after that something is waking up the PC. Same thing as when power saving kicks in. In recovery mode there is no such problem and now I am trying to pinpoint exactly which program is causing the problem...

Comment: Try unplugging the mouse before running xdpms.  Sometimes the mouse will sit on the fence on a pixel and act like it is moving when it is not.

Comment: Tried that but with no success. Tried even to boot without mouse but obviously it is not the mouse which wakes up the PC...

Comment: I'd next suggest a tool that can record X11 events (xev will sort of do it) and try to determine what events (like mouse movement or keystrokes) are causing the wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue comes after upgrade then Try to check if all upgrade using below commands, see if it helps.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

$ sudo apt --purge autoremove

$ sudo apt update --fix-missing

$ sudo reboot
```

If above steps doesn't work then there are below factors might possible for this issue.

1. Some Application is still running in the background which causing this.
2. Video or Hardware Driver Issue like incompatible video driver or Mouse touchpad driver which doesn't get suspended.

but before that please show us the output of this command (to check kernel version)

```
$ uname -r
```

Comment: 5.4.0-77-generic

Comment: I had same issue sometimes even before the upgrade to 20.04. It was happening after some kernel updates. Then, after the next kernel update disapeared...

Answer (score 0):

Then, Kernel must have a different compatibility factor with the mouse touchpad, Try installing Additional Kernel 5.8 then switch to that kernel from the boot menu and see if it works.

Kernel Download Link:

```
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/amd64/
```

Installing command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-modules-5.8.0-050800-generic_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Did not helped. Btw, It is a desktop, it does not have touchpad, just regular USB mouse...

Comment: Alright, Show me output of these commands,

`$ lsusb`

`$ uname -r`